# Replacing Teapot in Vuforia

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vuforia

I do not know anything in 3D modeling, for that I have person who works with 3D and modeling. I have started to work with Vuforia, and this is just awesome. I am trying to replace the teapot with my own 3D model. I have tried to stansform obj file with

http://www.rendoncepeda.com/home/projects/mtl2opengl/

but I did't got Indices in the new .h file. I dont know that this is and if I need it but in the Teapot.h file it have it. What is the simplest way to replace the teapot? I can ask from my 3D designer to export any format.

Comment: Please do not use converters that turn data into hadcoded source code. Even if it looks as it simplifies things at first, it makes life really difficult in the long term. Use a real asset loader library instead. Like AssIMP: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not have Indices,

instead of using this code to draw your object:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 
                     (const GLvoid*) &teapotIndices[0]);
```

use the following code:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);
```

Where numVertices is the number of vertices in your object.

Check [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/android-how-do-i-replace-teapot) for a more detailed explanation

Comment: and try to change the *`3D Model scale factor`*
    `const float kObjectScale = yourFloatValueHere;`in `EAGLView.mm` if its is not visible

Comment: I couldn't find this line of code in my ImageTargetsEAGLView class of Vuforia. How can I create that type of file of my custom object or I can use .png file instead that teapot

Answer (score 0):

What is the simplest way to replace the teapot?

Simplest way is using [Unity extension](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/unity). Unity is free and supports mobile platforms. If your scene doesn't have much objects and polygons (I think object culling needs pro version) Unity provides you a WYSWYG editor in realtime. You can find supported file formats here http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-importObject.html

Good luck on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer at Vuforia developer portal itself.
Here is link

[App related documents and tutorials](http://developer.vuforia.com/support)

[Replacing Teapot.h](http://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/How-To-Render-Static-3D-Models-Using-OpenGL-ES)